# Confusion about MQ Put options (IBM MQ)

Tags: ibm-mq

I am trying to understand some of the IBM MQ put options:

I have used https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=interfaces-mqputmessageoptionsnet-class for documentation.

1. It seems that `MQPMO_ASYNC_RESPONSE` and `MQPMO_SYNC_RESPONSE` in fact are mutually exclusive, yet these options have to different ID's (bit 12 and bit 13). What does MQ do when both options are set or neither one is set?
2. t seems that `MQPMO_SYNCPOINT` and `MQPMO_NO_SYNCPOINT` in fact are mutually exclusive, yet these options have to different ID's (bit 2 and bit 3). What does MQ do when both options are set or neither one is set?
3. `MQPMO_RESPONSE_AS_Q_DEF` makes things even more confusing for me. As I understand from the documentation this bit defers the control of the requests being synchronous or asynchronous to the queue definition. Therefore ignorning the options set with `MQPMO_ASYNC_RESPONSE` and `MQPMO_SYNC_RESPONSE`. But the documentation states the following

> For an MQDestination.put call, this option takes the put response type from DEFPRESP attribute of the queue.
> For an MQQueueManager.put call, this option causes the call to be made synchronously.

And the documentation for `DEFRESP` at https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.1?topic=queues-defpresp-mqlong is stating this:

> The default put response type (DEFPRESP) attribute defines the value used by applications when the PutResponseType within MQPMO has been set to MQPMO_RESPONSE_AS_Q_DEF. This attribute is valid for all queue types.
>
> The value is one of the following:
>
> - SYNC
>   The put operation is issued synchronously returning a response.
> - ASYNC
>   The put operation is issued asynchronously, returning a subset of MQMD fields.

But the other documentation says setting this option makes the call synchronous.

So in short: What happens with the seemingly mutually exclusive options and what does the `MQPMO_RESPONSE_AS_Q_DEF` really do?

Answer (score 2):

If you combine options flags that are not supposed to be combined, such as `MQPMO_SYNCPOINT` and `MQPMO_NO_SYNCPOINT` you will be return MQRC_OPTIONS_ERROR on the MQPUT call. you can see the documentation for this in IBM Docs [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=reference-rules-validating-mqi-options).

You are correct, the use of `MQPMO_RESPONSE_AS_Q_DEF` tells the queue manager to take the value for Put Response from the queue attribute `DEFPRESP`. The queue manager will look up the queue definition, and if it is `SYNC` it will effectively use `MQPMO_SYNC_RESPONSE` and if it is `ASYNC` it will effectively use `MQPMO_ASYNC_RESPONSE`.

The documentation you pointed us to states the following:-

> MQC.MQPMO_RESPONSE_AS_Q_DEF
>
> For an MQDestination.put call, this option takes the put response type from DEFPRESP attribute of the queue.
>
> For an MQQueueManager.put call, this option causes the call to be made synchronously.

I don't know why it would be different depending on the class used, but I can tell you that if the `MQPMO_RESPONSE_AS_Q_DEF` makes it to the queue manager it will change it as described above. This documentation suggests that the MQQueueManager class is changing it itself which is an odd decision.

Comment: Also of interest is that the value of MQPMO_RESPONSE_AS_Q_DEF is 0, so "setting" it is the same as leaving it unset, this also means MQPMO_RESPONSE_AS_Q_DEF+MQPMO_ASYNC_RESPONSE or MQPMO_RESPONSE_AS_Q_DEF+MQPMO_SYNC_RESPONSE will not error out and will behave as if MQPMO_RESPONSE_AS_Q_DEF was not specified.

Comment: @JoshMc Many of the default options are like that.

Comment: I know you know,  but thought the OP would be interested and may not know.

Comment: @JoshMc - Indeed - but the OP might be interested that it is not specific to PutResponse options too.

Comment: In the meanwhile I found this link also: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=mqpmo-options-mqlong 

So it seems that it is also possible to use publish/subscribe patterns for putting messages but again it is not mutually exclusive. I might just not being used to this kind of configuration.

Comment: @JoshMc and Morag you are both right, I was not aware at the time, but by reading a little bit more it seems a architectural pattern to use flags like that.

Comment: Yes @WilkovanderVeen the `MQPUT` verb can to used to put messages onto queues and to publish messages to topics. Think of it as IBM MQ's `send` verb. Many of the `MQPMO` options apply to both styles (which is why the same verb was used for both).